# Azure Server Instance Limit and Naming

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have signed up for the Free 90 day trial for Windows Azure.

I have also trawled questions, forums and articles for the questions I am about to ask but I cannot find the exact answer anywhere, not even on the microsoft site.

Just a brief outline on what I have been able to accomplish on Azure. I have been able to create a few servers and I have put a database on each of them. I have also been able to connect to the database from a windows desktop WPF application so the connection string is fine.

The thing is when I create the server instance, I am unable to give it a meaningful name. The server is assigned a name by Azure in the format of random numerics/characters , for example : jk059j60ei.

So Im not sure if in a Live Azure account, would I be able to name the server instance to something like : Customer 1, Customer2, Customer3 etc... ?? Does the random numeric/character naming just occur in the trial version??

Second question is, could I have 500 servers or 1000 if I wanted to ?
The reason being, each of our clients at the minute has their own on premises server with 3 databases. So if we were to migrate each of our clients to Azure, we would need a seperate server with separate databases for each client, as each database has to retain the same name. So each client connection string within their software must have a unique server name ( just like SQL server having a unique datasource or IP address )

One more question :) 
I created 1 virtual machine within the Azure portal but can only remote into it when im in the portal. Again, im wondering is this just a limitation of the trial version?
Or... in the live full version would I be able to remote or connect to the virtual machine remotely using an IP? Would Azure assign a public IP? At the minute they assign an internal virtual IP.

So take the following example : This might help make things more clear:

If we have 1000 clients, and we did away with each clients physical on site server and moved their database to the Azure platform, would it be better creating 1000 virtual servers with its own database? or.... is it possible to create 1000 virtual machines and install MS SQL Server on each of the virtual machines and install the database on those virtual machines?? Given that each of the virtual machines can have a public IP address which can be used in a connection string so that our software can access that database on the VM remotely.

Make sense??

I just cant find these answers anywhere and would greatly appreciate any answers from any one with Azure experience.

Look forward to all your responses.

Many Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try and assist with some of your questions:

> The thing is when I create the server instance, I am unable to give it a meaningful name.

As far as I know this will always be random, the only reasoning i've heard so far is the security through obscurity; I don't think you want an internet facing SQL instance name to be guessed. Don't be too concerned though, you still have server-level as well as database-level firewall configurations that you have control over.

> Second question is, could I have 500 servers or 1000 if I wanted to ?

You could pretty much have as many as your credit card can afford.

> would I be able to remote or connect to the virtual machine remotely
>   using an IP?

Not via IP as this could change; you would connect using the `*.cloudapp.net` dns name as port 3389 is opened automatically if you request RDP access. This works without having to go through the portal each time and is secured by admin username/password.

> So take the following example

With your example you have two choices :

- Each of your clients get its database residing in SQL Azure. SSMS + Portal Administration (probably your best bet) [read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336279.aspx)
- Each of your clients get its own self-managed VM with SQL Installed. Which would then largely relate to my comments above on the VMs. SSMS + RDP

Both of these options will still allow you to connect to the DB from a management perspective be it RDP or SSMS.

Comment: Hi f0x.. firstly thanks for getting back to me so quickly.. Secondly your answers are exactly what I have been looking for!!! They are precise, detailed and understandable. Hopefully more people will up the points on this answer as I think it will be more than useful to many other people. Thanks again and appreciated :)

Comment: @Kev Glad to hear I could help you!

Comment: Some answers here are not valid anymore. You can now give a database server a meaningful name like stackoverflow.database.windows.net. Also you can get reserved IP-addresses for a Virtual Machines.